# Get longest common substring based on string similarity

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a column that includes names like:

1. Home Improvement Guide
2. Home Improvement Advice
3. Home Improvement Costs
4. Home Gardening Tips

I would like the result to be:

1. Home Improvement
2. Home Gardening Tips

Based on a search for the word 'Home'.

This can be accomplished in MySQL or PHP or a combination of the two. I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure this out, any help in the right directly would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Edit / Problem kinda solved:

I think this problem can be solved much easier by changing the logic a little. For anyone else with this problem, here is my solution.

1. Get the sql results
2. Find the first occurrence of the searched word, one string at a time, and get the next word in the string to the right of it.
3. The results would include the searched word concatenated with the distinct adjoining word.

Not as good of a solution, but it works for my project. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: The logic that you're applying seems a little "human". What are the rules that you wish to apply?  How are the results decided?

Comment: You haven't actually clarified what you want. All of your example strings would match "Home"... why wouldn't they all be returned?

Comment: I am thinking the logic would need to first use a levenshtein function to find similarities in the sql results. The strings with similarities above a certain percentage would be applied to a longest common substring function. If no similarities are found then they would be included in the results as a unique value.

Comment: And what if one of the values where "Home Improvement Tips" or "Home Gardening Guide"?

Comment: I want to group similar results - As an example, on google you can search for the word home and you would get results that are a combination of many results shortened into a topic.

Comment: @GordonLinoff if the initial search was performed for Home Improvement Tips, and the database only consisted of those 4 values, then the result would be Home Improvement Tips. I only want to apply the longest common substring on the results, not on the database prior to the search being performed.

Comment: Did you try the 'full text' feature?

Comment: @Yani - I have full text enabled on the column if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

I don't think that Levenshtein distance does what you want.  Consider:

```
Home Improvement
Home Improvement Advice on Kitchen Remodeling
Home Gardening
```

The first and third are closer by the Levenshtein measure than the first and third.  And yet, I'm guessing that you want the first and second to be paired.

I have an idea of the algorithm you want.  Something like this:

- Compare every returned string to every other string
- Measure the length of the initial overlap
- Find the maximum over all the strings strings, pair those
- Repeat the process with the second largest overlap and so on

Painful, but not impossible to implement in SQL.  Maybe very painful.

What this suggests to me is that you are looking for a hierarchy among the products.  My suggestion is to just include a category column and return the category.  You may need to manually insert the categories into your data.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and brain power. Yes, I could make a category column - and I have consider this. However for this specific project I would really like to get the painful SQL approaching working if possible. I mean Google does this in their algorithm; how hard can it be?

Comment: And yes, I believe you are correct that Levenshtein is not the way to go.

Comment: Considering that Google (1) has probably over 10,000 developers; (2) writes custom code for all their applications; (3) has millions of person-hours invested in their code; (4) isn't using SQL for anything like this, the Google comparison doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: You're correct, I was just being funny with the Google comment.